# Why am I getting a CORS error depsite using flask_cors?

Tags: flask, cors

I'm getting the error

```
Access to fetch at 'http://hpap-dev.pmacs.upenn.edu:5801/get-categories' from origin 'http://hpap-dev.pmacs.upenn.edu:5802' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

despite using flask_cors. My flask app and route look like this

```
#Start flask app
app = Flask(__name__)
#Open flask for querying from domains outside of the app
CORS(app)

<snip>

@app.route('/get-categories')
@cross_origin()
def get_categories():
    frame_dict = file_cat_wrangle.get_wrangle_dict()
    
    # orig
    # return jsonify(response=frame_dict)
    # stauffer - try this to resolve CORS problem
    response = jsonify(response=frame_dict) 
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response
```

As you can see, the code's calling `CORS(app)` as well as `@cross_origin()` under the route. And I also tried adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header explicitly to the response, per another stackoverflow post.

I've rebuilt and restarted the flask server. AFAIK this used to work on this server (I've taken over this project at work and am pretty new to web dev). Other API calls that go between the front-end (node server) and back-end (the flask app) are working. I also checked that the route path and the call to it are identical.

Here's the call from the front end:

```
export const fetchCategories = () => {
  return fetch(`${flask_url}/get-categories`)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status >= 400) {
        throw new Error(`${response.status}: ${response.statusText}`);
      }
      return response.json();
    }).then(categories => categories);
}
```

Any suggestions??

Comment: UPDATE - it turns out it wasn't really a CORS error. Checking the Network tab in the browser debug tools, the headers were properly in place. The cause somehow was that the server's database entry for records did not match the actual data for each record on the filesystem. The CORS-related error also started not showing up and the page in question would simply hang w/out error or explanation. So I'll be digging into getting some better behavior when the database and filesystem are out of sync. But it's a mystery as to why a CORS error was reported when headers were in-place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was not actually a CORS-related error but some kind of odd error response. See my comment to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the header is really present in the network tab in your browser.
You can use hooks to enable cors as below:

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return response
```

Comment: I'll check that, thanks. But what does the second part of your answer do/mean? This will run after each route request and add the CORS header? Presumably that happens before it's checked by the browser for CORS compliance?

Comment: Right, this should be able to resolve your problem.